Eigenvalues of functions on finite discrete sets
Suppose I have an arbitrary function on a finite and discrete set $S$ defined as
$$f: S \times S \to \mathbb{C}^{|S|\times |S|}.$$
The $|S| \times |S|$ matrix $M$ is defined as
$$(M)_{ij}=f(s_i, s_j) \quad \mathrm{for} \ s_i,s_j \in S$$
I know the exact form of $f$ and from that I already know that $M$ is a hermitian and positive semi-definite matrix. Is there anything else I can learn about the eigenvalues of $M$ from the function $f$? Is there a recipe or set of general techniques I can use to find the eigenvalues of $M$ from $f$ and perhaps the structure of $S$?
